# TBB task blocked when not recursing any further

Tags: c++, tbb

```
struct root: public task
{
 root(){}
 tbb::task* execute(){
   tbb::task_list l;
   tbb::task& c = *new(allocate_continuation()) tbb::empty_task;
   int count=0;
   // do what this task should do 
   while(condition){
     l.push_back(*new(c.allocate_child())root());
     ++count;
   }
   if(count){
     c.set_ref_count(count);
     c.spawn(l);
   }
   return NULL;
 }
};
main(){
  tbb::task_scheduler_init s();
  root& r = *new(tbb::task::allocate_root())root();
  tbb::task::spawn_root_and_wait(r);
  return 0;
}
```

Hi, I've define a TBB task "root" that does some work and then recurses further if the `condition` in `while` loop is satisfied. If `count==0` after the `while` loop which means no further recursion is needed, then I won't generate more tasks.

Because what a `root` task does needs no continuation update, so I use `tbb::empty_task` to be the continuation task.

The problem is the execution is blocked by doing so. The program can not return normally. For now, my solution is:

```
if(!count){
  l.push_back(*new(c.allocate_child())tbb::empty_task);
  c.spawn(l);
  c.set_ref_count(1);
}
```

However, I presume the price is the performance. I desire to know why the original code doesn't work. It worked in another circumstance where the continuation task is not an empty task. I don't quite get the logic in there. Thank you for any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that when `count==0`, the task `c` is lost since it has no children and it is not spawned. The right way to deallocate a task is to call [`tbb::task::destroy`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_scheduler/explicit_task_destruction.html). But since you allocated it as a continuation, the responsibility to signal back to the `spawn_root_and_wait` that work is done is transferred to the task `c`. And since the task is lost, the signal is lost too which leads to the deadlock you observe. To do the signalling efficiently for the `count==0` case, just return the pointer to this `c` task as a result of `root::execute()` which is similar to doing the `spawn(c)` but avoids additional overheads for the synchronization.

Alternative is to do `c.parent()->decrement_ref_count()` and call to `destroy(c)` manually.

Comment: Thanks. It works when I return the pointer of continuation task while `count==0`. However, if I do `c.parent()->decrement_ref_count()` and `task::destroy(c)` instead, it blocks again. I think it is because the continuation task is not yet spawned before it is destroyed.

Comment: @Alex, do you do decrement and destroy in `count==0` case only? a task can be either spawned or destroyed because spawned task is destroyed automatically. It is strange that it still blocks